# D3 shape to follow path

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

Hi this is my first post.  I've searched for a good tutorial to help finish this D3 line chart - but haven't found what I'm looking for.  All I need to do is get the orange circle to follow the same path as the dotted line.  At the moment it has a straight path.  Thanks for any help on this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IEMobile 7 ]><html class="no-js iem7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]><html class="no-js lte-ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 8)|(gt IEMobile 7)|!(IEMobile)|!(IE)]><!-->
<html lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Drawdown line chart</title>

    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

    <style>
    body {font: 15px sans-serif;}
    .container{max-width:990px}
    h2{float:left; width:100%; text-align:center; font-size:30px; color:#666666; margin:20px 0 30px}
    .highlight{color:#f26522}
    #chart{width:90%; margin:0 10%}

    .domain {fill: none; stroke: gray; stroke-width: 1;}

    </style>


</head>

    <body> 

        <div class="container">

            <h2>Click the <span class="highlight">orange dot</span> to start:</h2>

            <div class="row">
                <div id="chart" class="col-sm-12">

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            // Chart data
            var dataArray = [
            {"x":0, "y":100000},
            {"x":1, "y":90000},
            {"x":2, "y":83000},
            {"x":3, "y":73000},
            {"x":4, "y":79000},
            {"x":5, "y":72000},
            {"x":6, "y":75000},
            {"x":7, "y":88000},
            {"x":8, "y":63000},
            {"x":9, "y":71000},
            {"x":10, "y":69000},
            {"x":11, "y":63000},
            {"x":12, "y":67000},
            {"x":13, "y":63000},
            {"x":14, "y":59000},
            {"x":15, "y":46000},
            {"x":16, "y":40000},
            {"x":17, "y":32000},
            {"x":18, "y":29000},
            {"x":19, "y":20000},
            {"x":20, "y":18000},
            {"x":21, "y":17000},
            {"x":22, "y":9000},
            {"x":23, "y":0},
            {"x":24, "y":0},
            {"x":25, "y":0},
            {"x":26, "y":0},
            {"x":27, "y":0},
            {"x":28, "y":0},
            {"x":29, "y":0},
            {"x":30, "y":0}
            ];


            // Variables

            var currentAge = 65
            var longevity = 92
            var yearsToLive = longevity - currentAge
            var years = dataArray.length
            var totalDrawdown = dataArray[0].y 
            var chartWidth = 800
            var chartHeight = 400
            var chartMargin = 20
            var axisHeight = 20

            var widthScale = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([currentAge, currentAge + years])
                .range([0, chartWidth - chartMargin]);

            var axis = d3.svg.axis()
                .ticks(5)
                .tickSize(20)
                .scale(widthScale);

            // Chart scaling
            x_scale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,years]).range([0, chartWidth]);
            y_scale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,totalDrawdown]).range([chartHeight - chartMargin,0]);


            var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
                .x(function(d) { return x_scale(d.x) })
                .y(function(d) { return y_scale(d.y) });


            function getSmoothInterpolation() {
                var interpolate = d3.scale.linear()
                        .domain([0,1])
                        .range([1, dataArray.length + 1]);

                return function(t) {
                        var flooredX = Math.floor(interpolate(t));
                        var interpolatedLine = dataArray.slice(0, flooredX);

                        if(flooredX > 0 && flooredX < dataArray.length) {
                            var weight = interpolate(t) - flooredX;
                            var weightedLineAverage = dataArray[flooredX].y * weight + dataArray[flooredX-1].y * (1-weight);
                            interpolatedLine.push({"x":interpolate(t)-1, "y":weightedLineAverage});
                        }

                        return lineFunction(interpolatedLine);
                    }
                }


            // Canvas   
            var canvas = d3.select ("#chart")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", chartWidth)
                .attr("height", chartHeight + axisHeight)
                .attr("id", "lineChart");


            // Longevity marker
            var rectangle = canvas.append("rect")
                .attr("width", (chartWidth/years) * ((currentAge + years) - longevity))
                .attr("height", chartHeight - chartMargin)
                .attr("x",  (chartWidth/years) * (longevity - currentAge) )
                .attr("fill","#f2f2f2");


            // Destination range

            var outer = canvas.append("rect")
                .attr("width", 200)
                .attr("height", 10)
                .attr("x",  525 )
                .attr("y",  380 )
                .attr("fill","#f2f2f2");

            var inner = canvas.append("rect")
                .attr("width", 75)
                .attr("height", 10)
                .attr("x",  588 )
                .attr("y",  380 )
                .attr("fill","#d1d1d1");    


            var likely = canvas.append("rect")
                .attr("width", 10)
                .attr("height", 10)
                .attr("x",  620 )
                .attr("y",  380 )
                .attr("fill","#666666");    


            // Chart path
            canvas.append("path")
                .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                .attr("stroke", "gray")
                .attr("fill", "none")
                .attr("id", "journey")
                .style("stroke-dasharray", ("3, 3"))
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + chartMargin + ", 0)")

            // Moving circle
            var marker = canvas.append("circle")
                .attr("id", "marker")
                .attr("cx", 5 + chartMargin)
                .attr("cy", 10)
                .attr("r", 10)
                .attr('fill', '#f26522');


            // Add x axis
            canvas.append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate("+ chartMargin + "," + (chartHeight - chartMargin) + ")")
                .attr("fill","#aaaaaa")             
                .call(axis);



            // Add start button
            d3.select('#lineChart')
                .append('circle')
                .attr("cx", 5 + chartMargin)
                .attr("cy", 10)
                .attr("r", 10)
                .attr('fill', '#f26522')
                .on('click', function() {
                    d3.select('#lineChart > #journey')
                        .transition()
                        .duration(6000)
                        .attrTween('d', getSmoothInterpolation );


                    d3.select('#lineChart > #marker')
                        .transition()
                        .duration(6000)
                        .attrTween("cx", function (d, i, a) { return d3.interpolate(a, 620) })
                        .attrTween("cy", function (d, i, a) { return d3.interpolate(a, 400) });

                });

            </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my try:

Instead of translating the circle via transition like this in the click function:

```
           d3.select('#lineChart > #marker')
                .transition()
                .duration(6000)
                .attrTween("cx", function (d, i, a) { return d3.interpolate(a, 620) })
                .attrTween("cy", function (d, i, a) { return d3.interpolate(a, 400) });
```

Move the circle animation also with in the path animation like below:

```
function getSmoothInterpolation() {
                var interpolate = d3.scale.linear()
                        .domain([0,1])
                        .range([1, dataArray.length + 1]);

                return function(t) {
                        var flooredX = Math.floor(interpolate(t));
                        var interpolatedLine = dataArray.slice(0, flooredX);
                        if(flooredX > 0 && flooredX < dataArray.length) {
                            var weight = interpolate(t) - flooredX;
                            var weightedLineAverage = dataArray[flooredX].y * weight + dataArray[flooredX-1].y * (1-weight);
                            interpolatedLine.push({"x":interpolate(t)-1, "y":weightedLineAverage});
                            //get the length of the path
                            var len = d3.select("#journey").node().getTotalLength();
                            //get the svg point at that length
                            var pt = d3.select("#journey").node().getPointAtLength(len);
                            //translate the circle to that point.
                            d3.select('#lineChart > #marker').attr("transform", "translate(" +pt.x + "," + pt.y + ")");
                        }

                        return lineFunction(interpolatedLine);
                    }
                }
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/nO0U7Tpe7Mo230DJyB8J?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply Cyril - that works nicely in Chrome.  I'm getting an error in Firefox, however.  Is there an easy way round this?: 

'NS_ERROR_FAILURE: 
 var pt = d3.select("#journey").node().getPointAtLength(len);'

Comment: I think `var len = d3.select("#journey").node().getTotalLength();` this is coming out to be null initially in FF. May be you need a check to filter those cases. I dont think there is any other way out. If you find then please update that in here, will be something new..Thanks!